# How to get Webpack to use already existing source maps when generating source maps?

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I have JavaScript code and source maps generated from TypeScript code (using `tsc`).

I then have a second compilation step which bundles the code using `webpack`.

I have enabled source maps in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map"
}
```

The generated source map isn't entirely right.

Webpack is not taking into account the existing source maps that have been generated from TypeScript code.

This results in a mapping to the JavaScript code instead of the TypeScript code.

How can I get the Webpack source map to include existing mapping?

**EDIT:**

After renaming my question, and searching for my renamed question on Google, I found an answer.

You can use a preloader with webpack called `source-map-loader`: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/source-map-loader/

However, after installing `source-map-loader` and updating `webpack.config.js` to the following, the existing source maps are still not used:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
        enforce: "pre"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My guess is that because the files my existing source map point to are located outside the `entry` directory in `webpack.config.js`, they are ignored...?

Comment: Yes, your question title should definitely change: _how to get Webpack to use already existing source maps when generating source maps?_ - Your current config is doing exactly what you've asked it to do. The Typescript is not mapped by webpack and existing maps won't reflect what is in the bundle, but what is in the transpired JavaScript. Not sure there is a way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I've updated the question. That would be disappointing if there were no solution.

Comment: Well, I think we need to think about this in two ways: 1) what do the original source maps (SM) point to? The typescript reflected from transpiled JavaScript. If the transpiled JavaScript file is removed or changed the SM breaks. So simply including the original SM won't work. 2) web pack workflow: transpile TS, place into bundle at reference line number, write SM based upon _where the transpiled JS is in bundle_. That's the part of the workflow that cannot be accomplished outside of the bundle creation.

Comment: 1) I was hoping there would be a way to sort of prune the mappings. So if A in bundled is mapped to B in js, and B in js is mapped to C in ts, then A could be mapped directly to C. 2) I wish the TypeScript could be transpiled inside webpack, but I have code shared by server, client and other builds. My react native client, for example, is using a different built-in bundler. 3) Maybe there's a different bundler I can use to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transpile the typescript as part of webpack, you will get the source maps with it.

```
devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ([
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: 'tsconfig.json' }
          },
```

you need devTool: 'source-map' in webpack
and the "sourceMap": true in tsconfig.json

devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
provides a faster build to generate source maps in development. But it will put the source mapping inline. So not for production.

So the big question. Why have a step separated from webpack?

If you use AOT compilation with angular (with the ngc command from @anguler/compiler), and produce .map files in the aot folder, then you want to reuse the map files. I can tell you I tested it to work with the solution below.

Then this will make it work:

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: ["source-map-loader"],
    enforce: "pre"
  },
```

And it is important you have sourceMap: true in tsconfig, and in the minimizer if you use one:

```
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true, // Must be set to true if using source-maps in production
        terserOptions: {
          // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#terseroptions
        }
```

I have a tsconfig.json in development
a tsconfig_ao1.json for ngc command
I have a tsconfig_ao2.json to compile with aot the main.ts using the aot folder. And I use ngc outside of webpack because I could not use @ngtools/webpack inside webpack without issues.

If you are doing something else, you ened to understand the source-map-load will only load source maps if the files it test matches has source maps, and if the files art part of the tree loaded from the entry. There must be an import from the main.ts to the file that is source mapped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look at it when I get a chance.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you have said... I have `build`, `dist` and `src` folders. TypeScript is taking input from `src` and generating output along with source maps in `dist` folder. Webpack has entry of `dist` folder and is outputting to `build` folder. Could it not be working because the original TypeScript code is in the `src` folder, but webpack entry is `dist` folder and therefore ignores the original TypeScript code when generating source maps (since the TypeScript source maps are pointing to files outside the webpack entry)? If this is the case, how do I fix this do you know?

Comment: Symbolic links may cause problems sometimes, for example if your dist is a symbolic link to a map. An entry is not a folder, an entry is a file that is the root of your program (like a main() in C). ANd this file must import a relative path to your generated js file (output of ts generation). I made it work with build and aot separate folders. You must simplify your webpack config. For example if you have an exclude rule, it may exclude some files. Webpack needs practice. I suspect your typescript compiler is strange. Maybe change it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant webpack has entry of `dist/main.js`. No I'm not using any symbolic links. My entry for webpack isn't a file which imports one of the generated JS files, but instead is the main generated JS file `dist/main.js`. But I assume that should work the same. I'm afraid I need separate compilation steps because I'm creating a monorepo with shared code between server and client, and server is using webpack as bundler and client is using react-native bundler, and any of my "packages" should be compilable independently (using TypeScript) so that they can be tested, used on their own, etc.

Comment: I have no exclude rules or anything.. I'll try set up a simple example that doesn't work when I get a chance. And if it does end up working then I know I have some mistake in my current project.

Comment: loaders, like the source-map-loaders, are only run on modules. To have a module you need to import it. So try this: create a new entry point file that imports the dist/main.ts. Then you will have a module. And change the webpack entry point to that new file. Does it work? OK to have different parts and share code. Maybe restructure the dist/main so that it has an export. be careful between the various import x and import * as x and import { x }

Comment: I have a similar setup as @DavidCallanan, and also cannot get the source-maps from my lib's `dist` folder integrated into the overall source-maps for the project using it. I've just given up for now, but will update here if I find a fix.

Comment: @Venryx Good luck with that anyways! Simple things have gotten so difficult. This question was for an old project so I can't even remember if I got it working in the end.

Comment: You should try to go on a forum and ask with an online code sample. I can't advertise one here. But a good forum starts with S and ends with T, with 9 letters.